# Proving orientability of manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I don't know how to prove the following:
$RP^n$ is orientable manifold if n is odd?

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Decide when the antipodal map on $S^n$ is orientation-preserving.